# Defining ember models for dynamic json response

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I have a json response which provides the following data

```
{
"persons":[
    {
        "name" : "yyy"
    },
    {
        "name" : "zzz"
    }
]
```

}

and my ember model is defined as follows

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
name : DS.attr("string")
```

});

Suppose in future my json response changes as follows

```
{
"persons":[
    {
        "country" : "yyy"
    },
    {
        "country" : "zzz"
    }
]
```

}

or some attributes is added like

```
{
"persons":[
    {
        "name"   : "yyy",   
        "country"  : "yyy"
    },
    {
        "name"   : "zzz",   
        "country" : "zzz"
    }
]
```

}
We need to update the ember model for working with these responses. How to define generic ember models to respond to any json response

Comment: Why would you want this? If you were to have such a model, then you could not make any assumptions about its attributes in the controller/template

Comment: Agree with @ThomasBrus, no point in defining Ember properties on an object unless you know how to observe them or bind to them.